# Convert and multiply currency string eval values in an ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, formatexception

I am trying to convert two string values to integers, and multiply them, to use in a ListView on an ASPX page.

The following code doesn't work, but it should give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<%#String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToInt32(Eval("nbrQtyOrdered")) * Convert.ToInt32(Eval("curSellPrice"))) %>
```

I am getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

`nbrQtyOrdered` is a string representation of an integer value and `curSellPrice` is a string representation of a double written as "$22.22", for example. I am assuming now the dollar sign is giving me the error.

How can I fix this problem and achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What have you tried? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @MaCron An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: what are your input values? have you tried debugging this to make sure everything is what you think it should be?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `"$22.22"` with a dollar sign cannot be converted to an Integer.

I would suggest first trimming the dollar sign. This can be done multiple ways:

```
Eval("curSellPrice").Replace("$", "")
```

OR

```
Eval("curSellPrice").TrimStart('$');
```

Once you remove the dollar sign from the `curSellPrice` string, you should be able to use it with `Convert.ToInt32()` .

Comment: I can do that, however i need to pass 2 values

Comment: @cjtampa What do you mean by "need to pass 2 values"? In the example that your provided, you would just replace `Convert.ToInt32(Eval("curSellPrice"))` with `Convert.ToInt32(Eval("curSellPrice").TrimStart('$'))` and leave the rest of the expression the same.

Comment: @cjtampa You may need to add `.ToString()` after the `Eval()`.